# Open doc file with interop is null in IIS 8.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I try open .doc file with interop, when I run in Visual studio result is a file but I publish web to IIS result is null. 
I added folder Desktop to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile, I run website, process Word run but still no return result.
I'm using Windows server 2012 64bit and Microsoft Office 2007. Why result in IIS return null and solution?

```
 var wordApp = new Application { Visible = false };
 var path = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "File\\TestFile.doc";
 object srcPath = path;
 var wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref srcPath);
```

Comment: I hope you understand that Microsoft explicitly suggests that you shouldn't try to interop with Office from services? What does your debugging show? Does your wordApp variable even get set?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Answer (score 0):

[Refer Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0f5448a7-72ed-4f16-8b87-922b71892e07/word-2007-documentsopen-returns-null-in-aspnet)

Sometimes with Office interop stuff it can be awkward.

If you use a single user to access the word application i.e. your asp.net service username.

Then what you can do is login to the computer using that username and open up word, this then adds all the registry and file system changes that the office applications seem to use.  Note: if you are planning on using Excel as well then you need to open up excel also.

Another method is to create a new user account for accessing Word, then do the above and in your code behind impersonate that user so you're not giving the Web Application User access to word.

Hope this helps

p.s. When working with office interop it's important to watch for dirty references to objects.  Leaving dirty references leaves ghost Word/Excel processes (visible only in task manager).

One thing I always do to help is to create a new AppDomain, this means there is no risk to the current process. Then I always release the objects as follows

```
if (item != null)

{ 

 while (Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item) > 0); 
 item = null;

}
```

Where item is a document object, an application object etc.  This code should go in a Finally block so that it always runs

Just in case you're new to office interop this one kept me busy for quite some time when I was just starting out.